# Rank of Matrix $M_{ij} = (i-j)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the following:

Let $M$ be a matrix such that $M_{ij} = (i-j)^2$.
The author says "It is easy to see that $\operatorname{rank}(M) = 3$", but I fail to understand how the rank is $3$ for any matrix $M$ of any size and how he can find it ‘easily’.

What is the intuition behind it? I know how to compute the rank of a matrix given a normal matrix with values, but I fail to see how to do it given the form of the matrix like in this example.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a size for this matrix? I guarantee it doesn't hold for the $2 \times 2$ case!

Comment: It says: . Let M ∈ $M_{n×n}$, where $M_{ij}=...$ Nothing about n, but just for the sake of the question assume:  n>=3 I tried to manually compute for n=3,4,5 and it seems to hold...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(i - j)^2 = i^2 - 2ij + j^2$. Let $(A)_{ij}$, $(B)_{ij}$, and $(C)_{ij}$ be, respectively, $i^2$, $ij$, and $j^2$ respectively. Then $M = A - 2B + C$.

We now note that the ranks of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all $1$. The rows of $A$ are all parallel to $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$, and $C$ is just the transpose of $A$. We also have $B = vv^\top$, where $v = (1, 2, \ldots, n)^\top$. This implies that $M$ has rank *at most* $3$.

To show that the rank is $3$ for $n \ge 3$, just show it for the $n = 3$ case, in which case we have a full rank $3 \times 3$ submatrix, which provides a lower bound of $3$ on the rank of $M$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT

The rank is  $\le 3$ being the sum of three matrices of rank $1$ : $i^2$, $-2 i j$ and $j^2$.

Now   show that  $\det( (a_i-b_j)^{2})_{1\le i,j\le 3}\ne 0$, if $a_i$, $b_i$ are two groups of distinct numbers.